# How can I extract files with names more than 260 characters in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, winrar

I am downloading lot of stuff in `rar` files on Windows. But when I extract them, I get a 260 character limit problem.

I can make the path shorter, but is there any way I can extract the files in such a way that the problem doesn't occur?

Comment: Do it by hand.  View the contents and drag and drop

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/345894) for an alternative workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating a folder in the root directory of one of your hard drives, naming this new folder with a one-letter name; then, extract into that folder. Hopefully this will make the total file name (including the path) short enough allow you to get access to the files.

Answer (score 2):

As shown on the [Wikipedia Page for NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS), the maximum length for a filename (including the path) is 255 characters. Using a different tool will not likely fix the issue you are having. What you will need to do is extract to a very short-named folder on the root of a drive. Depending how the archive is packed, you may need to select some files manually, or rename folders, to get it working properly.

Another method is to use the [`SUBST`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true) command to substitute a long pathname that you are extracting to as a new drive. As an example, you can run `SUBST x: C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\ExtractedArchive`. You will only be able to access the longer files through the new drive, but you can at least extract the files and move them to wherever you may need them to be.

Comment: i tried that but sometime the folders are deep nested

Comment: Again, you may need to manually select some files and extract them separately.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I used 7-zip for extracting and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Related answer from "How to unzip zip archives that have more than 260 symbols in their name?" https://superuser.com/a/944668/365218