# Windows 11 path too long issue persists after regedit

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11, path

I followed the recommended steps to solve the `path too long` issue on Windows 11 *(Insider Preview v23H2, b25951.1010)*; nevertheless, the problem persists, as I still get error `path too long` when unzipping certain folders:

1. Launch `regedit` → Navigate to:

   ```
   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
   ```
2. `LongPathsEnabled`: `1`
3. Save and Reboot

Comment: Have you rebooted after making this registry edit? How are you unzipping?

Comment: Possible work-around: Create a folder such as C:\tmp, with a very short filename, and unzip into that, or even into the root directory of drive *other* than C:, to shorten the path. See https://superuser.com/questions/345894/how-to-unzip-zip-archives-that-have-more-than-260-symbols-in-their-name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unzip zip archives that have more than 260 symbols in their name?](https://superuser.com/questions/345894/how-to-unzip-zip-archives-that-have-more-than-260-symbols-in-their-name)