# Unzip and 7z with password, without temporary files

Tags: windows, command-line, zip, wget, 7-zip

Every now and then, I receive a download link for a 6 GB .zip data archive that I'd like to:

- download
- unzip
- recompress with 7z, with a password

I'd like to avoid using temporary files for each step, because it would use ~ 18 GB of write operations on my SSD, whereas only 6 GB are necessary at the end.

On Linux, it would probably be `wget ... | unzip ... | 7z ...` with pipes.

**How to do this on Windows?**

---

Note: this question is linked to [Make 7-Zip extract an archive directly to a directory](https://superuser.com/questions/197961/make-7-zip-extract-an-archive-directly-to-a-directory) but not a duplicate, because the linked question only covers the "7z temp" part of the question, whereas I'm speaking about a download+unzip+7z chain.
Also I'm looking for a **command-line solution**, and not a drag'n'drop GUI solution like [Make 7-Zip extract an archive directly to a directory](https://superuser.com/questions/197961/make-7-zip-extract-an-archive-directly-to-a-directory).

Comment: Why do you consider 18GB of write to be an issue? Space constraints or… wear-rate paranoia?

Comment: @Tetsujin OPs mention of "write operations" indicates that is the case.

Comment: @music2myear - I kind of guessed that, but I just wanted confirmation ;)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, because the linked question only covers the "7z temp" part of the question, whereas I'm speaking about a download+unzip+7z chain :)

Comment: This operation is a bad fit for pipes or the like. You cannot really pipe multiple files around, because it’s not _just data_. They also have names. // This operation in general is very feasible. However, you need a purpose-made program to do it.

Comment: Using temp files would double only the Compress or Decompress stages. Assuming minimal compression and no temp files, downloading writes 6GB, decompressing writes a further 6GB, and compress writes a final 6GB, still totaling 18GB. Assuming a worst-case where both the decompress and compress stages use temp files, that total would balloon to 30GB. The only option to reduce writes to your SSD below 18GB would be to use a different disk to store the file, or to use a RAM disk of some sort.

Comment: Further, the answer I flagged as duplicate notes the reason 7zip uses temp files is when the OS is handling the target portion of the process. Using the standard 7zip command line tools, the application would be handling the target portion of the process and so not temp file would be used. The duplicate is still the duplicate.

Comment: You're right @DanielB, it would be complex with multiple files. Fortunately I only need 1 file from the original file (a Google Takeout archive with a `.mbox` file), see https://superuser.com/questions/1613860/unzip-and-7z-with-password-without-temporary-files/1613998#1613998

Comment: @music2myear Yes it could easily go up to 30GB. I'm currently using a RAMdisk indeed to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command-line solution avoids temporary files for decompression/compression, and works on Windows. It uses `-so` and `-si` stdout/stdin flags of `7z`.

```
7z e -so -r Takeout20201231_0941.zip *.mbox | 7z a -si -pSECRET -mhe=on -mx=2 Takeout20201231_0941.7z
```

Note that there is only 1 match for `*.mbox` in my original archive, so there is only one file to be decompressed / compressed.

With multiple files, it would more complex, as noted by @DanielB in his comment:

> This operation is a bad fit for pipes or the like. You cannot really pipe multiple files around, because it’s not just data. They also have names.

---

Lastly, piping the download of the original ZIP directly to `7z e` wouldn't be possible because ZIP files can't be stream-decompressed: they often have an index *at the end of the file*, thus requiring the *whole file* first before starting to decompress.

For this, we can quickly create a RAM disk `X:\` with OSFMount:

```
osfmount.com -a -t vm -m X: -s 8G -o format:ntfs
```